# How to implement revisioning in my own module?

Tags: 7, nodes

In my module I store some node related data in a specific table of the database. Now I want to implement the revisioning system, so I create `my_table_revision` with the same information and a new column called `revision_id`.

But, How can I know when a new `revsion` of the node is created? and how can I know when a node `revision` is reverted?

It exists something like `hook_revert()` or `hook_revision`?

Comment: Why can't you use Drupal's built-in node revisioning system (and the already existing modules built on it to examine and revert revisions)?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the Drupal's built-in node reversioning system but I have a separate database table (that needs to be reversioned).

Comment: @ilaz That's not how it works. Revisions refer to an entity (of which 'node' is a type); if you want to use revisions with a custom table, you need to create a custom entity with Drupal's API that uses that table (or actually 2 tables, one for data, one for revisions), for storage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [Free Radical](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12076/free-radical) and [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) says the best way to implement a revisioning system is creating a custom entity. But if you can't create a custom entity and you have to use your own table, I answer here what I have done.

So, you have your `table` and you have to create a `table_revision` with the same fields and one mor field called `revision`.

With the [`hook_node_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) you can control when a node is updated, even when a node is revisioned.

So in the `$node` argument of the `hook_node_update` you have three `vid` (revision ID): `$node->vid`, `$node->old_vid` and `$node->original->vid`. The `$node->vid` is the new `vid`, the `$node->original->vid` is the previous `vid` that the node had, and the `$node->old_vid` is the `vid` of the node where you revert.

If the `$node->old_vid` is the same value than `$node->original->vid` means that the node is edited and not reverted, and if it is not the same value, it means that the node is reverted to a previous revision.

If the node is edited, you have to insert the new values in the `table_revision` with the '$node->vid`revision ID. But if the node is reverted, you have to get the old values from the`table_revision`with`revision_id = $node->old_vid`and then copy this values in the`table`and`table_revision`with the`$node->vid`as new`revision_id`.

Answer (score 2):

As Clive says, you need to create a custom entity (with the API) to hold the data. Then Drupal will create the necessary tables and take care of the versioning for you.

If you need to do special things (that is not already done by Drupal's built-in versioning), you can intercept both saving of new revisions and reversals with [`hook_entity_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7).

AFAIK, there is no simple way to tell a new revision apart from a reversal.  Technically, a reversal results in a new revision with a new version ID (`vid`) being created, where the *content* of the new revision just happens to be identical to some old revision.

If it is really important for you to tell them apart, I guess you could keep a table with SHA2 (or MD5) hash signature for each revision, and look up the signature in that table to identify a reversal.

For the sake of completeness, I'll also mention that I've observed than when someone do a reversal, a log message is generated and placed in {node_revision.log} (E.g. "`Copy of the revision from <em class="placeholder">Thu, 2014-06-19 13:53</em>.`". Otherwise, this field is filled in with a user-written change notice (or left blank). You may be able to use this to detect reversals, but IMHO this method is not reliable as the string can easily be spoofed by a user who knows about this.

Comment: I don't use revisions very often...would a reversal result in a new revision ID, or does it use the one from the original revision? If the former then maybe that's the way to distinguish?

Comment: It generates a brand new `vid` for reversals.  Only thing that distinguishes reversals from other saves is that it generates a log message on reversals (E.g. "`Copy of the revision from <em class="placeholder">Thu, 2014-06-19 13:53</em>.`" while the `log` field in `{node_revision}` is empty in the case of an ordinary save of revised content. So I guess you could poll the `log` field to detect a reversal.

Comment: Just to correct my self: The `log` field is not necessarily empty. If the change is *not* a reversal, it contains whatever change notice the user types in - I am just in the habit of leaving it blank.